# Where can one find the meid of an iOS Device? (in particular an iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad, cellular-carriers, cellular-data, meid

I'm getting 4G on my iPad 2 and the Sales Rep for Verizon said that I needed to text him the `meid`, where in iOS might I find this `meid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Settings app > General > About**

The various ID used for cellular networking and services are listed immediately above the Modem Firmware field.

Answer (score 1):

Look on the back; the MEID should be engraved there. 
Alternately, look in the Settings App under General then About for "IMEI". The MEID is either the same as the IMEI  or just the first 14 chsracters of the IMEI.